How can I get to the back of the Ollivander's Shop in Hogsmeade?
I'd like to have a closer look at the portraits and things in the back of Mr Ollivander's shop:

But it doesn't seem like I'm able to. I tried jumping over the desk, but I was not able to. There doesn't seem to be a door or way behind the building either.
Is it somehow possible to get into the back side of the shop to have a closer look at the things there?

IIRC you only go there once during a specific quest, or perhaps only after completing that quest during your playthrough.
